# Get website ranking information in real time

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I came into this question during an interview.

Let say we have log information for user visiting a website, the information including website, user, time. We need to design a data structure that we can get the information of

- Top five visiting user of a specific website
- Top five website visit by a specific user
- Websites that are only be visited for 100 times in a day

All in real time

The first thought that I came in mind is that we can just use a database to store the log and every time we just need to do counting and sorting for each user or each website. But it's not real time as we need to do a lot of computation to get the information.

Then I think we can use HashMap for each problem. For example, for each website we use `HashMap<Website, <TreeMap<User, count>>`, so that we can get the top five visitor for a specific website. But the interviewer said we can only use one data structure for all three problem as the second problem would use `HashMap<User, <TreeMap<Website, count>>`, which has different key and value type.

Can anyone think of a good solution for this problem?

Comment: TreeMap is just a specific implementation of a Map, like a HashMap. Therefore, the answer is just "Map", no?

Comment: @cricket_007 Let me clarify the question a little bit. For example, the top five visiting user, we may want to construct an HashMap<Website, TreeMap<User, Count>>, but for top five website is HashMap<User, TreeMap<Website, Count>>, the key and value type is different, so it's different

Comment: And what's wrong with a database? At work, I have a live dashboard of the top 20 users of an internal website

Comment: @cricket_007 The interviewer said as we need to do sorting when we query the database. It's not real time.

Comment: SQL `ORDER BY` isn't slow...

Comment: @cricket_007 I know. I even said we can use MapReduce to speed up the counting process. But the interviewer is not happy about that. I guess he's asking for a O(1) time data structure.

Comment: MapReduce is much slower than SQL. The dashboard I was mentioning earlier uses ElasticSearch as the backend, though

Comment: I think you won't need the second HashMap if the ```User``` class itself contains a set of visited websites, and the comparator is the number of visits, so the set would be sorted according to that.

Comment: @IslamHassan I am aware of that. But it's still using different data structure for different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A map of maps, with generic types, as a **basic approach**.

The first map represents the global data structure, which will contain the maps for the three problems.

The first inside map, you'll have the website as the key and a list of the top 5 users.

The second inside  map, you'll have the user as a key and a list of the top 5 visited website by him.

For the last problem, you can have the websites as key and the number of visitors as value on the third inside map.

If what they meant was to have the same data structure for three different problems, thant forget about the global map.

If you want to go a litle deeper, you can consider using a **adjacency matrix** implementation where your users and websites identifications are your columns/rows identifiers and the values are the number of visitors.

Comment: With adjacency matrix, we still need to do the sorting in order to get top 5 and that's not real time. I think it's not solving the problem neither.

Comment: You can make it real time and ordered. Like the insertion methods of a leaf on a tree, you can make the insertion of an adjacency matrix ordered and you also have algorithms that give the intended results.

If you want more computing power with a db involved, consider using indexes for a faster search and basic lists for storing the retrieved data.